# Is Path::new(many-subdirs) good enough for both Linux and Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, rust

I have no Windows machine right now, but I want to make my code cross-platform. I have working code from `build.rs` that works on Linux:

```
Path::new("dir1/dir2/dir3")
```

Is this correct for Windows or should I use something like:

```
Path::new("dir1").join("dir2").join("dir3")
```

Comment: More precisely, if someone had a computer with windows, he could test if something like `/c/users/johndoe` is parsed as `C:\Users\JohnDoe`

Comment: @Boiethios Or somebody have knowledge how std lib implementing on windows

Answer (score 5):

"Good enough" is a tricky question. Both of them work to identify a path because Windows treats forward slashes (`/`) the same as backwards slashes (`\`).

However, if you ever *show* the path to your user (remember about error messages too!), then you should strive to meet the expectations of the platform:

```
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    let p = Path::new("target/debug");
    println!("{}", p.exists());
    println!("{}", p.display());

    let p = Path::new("target").join("debug");
    println!("{}", p.exists());
    println!("{}", p.display());
}
```

```
true
target/debug
true
target\debug
```

Additionally, if you were to build on another path, mixing the two styles looks *really* bad:

```
fn main() {
    let cwd = std::env::current_dir().expect("No CWD");

    let p = cwd.join("target/debug");
    println!("{}", p.exists());
    println!("{}", p.display());

    let p = cwd.join("target").join("debug");
    println!("{}", p.exists());
    println!("{}", p.display());
}
```

```
true
c:\Rust\dirs\target/debug
true
c:\Rust\dirs\target\debug
```

Answer (score 3):

`Path::new("dir1/dir2/dir3")` should be completely valid on Windows.

For example:

```
fn main() {
    let path = Path::new("test/add_folder/hello.txt");

    let mut file = File::create(path).unwrap();
    file.write_all(b"Hello, world!").unwrap();
}
```

is working without a problem on Windows, as long as the required folders exist.

---

**However,** to access something like

> C:\Users\JohnDoe

`/c/users/johndoe` does not work, you need to write `c:/users/johndoe` instead.